# In BigQuery, how to random split query results?

Tags: sql, random, google-bigquery, ansi-sql

In BigQuery (standard SQL), I would like to randomly split result lines from a query.

- The split needs to be consistent and should not change over time: meaning that every time the query is ran, the split should remain the same.
- In particular, if data is added to the source table, data previously in one side of the split should remain in the same split.
- The strategy should be able to handle different splitting ratios

I currently have, for instance, for a table `mytable`, with columns (`order_id`, `created_at`, `country`):

for a 10%/90% split, on the one hand

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   `mytable`
WHERE RAND() <= 10/90
```

on the other hand

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   `mytable`
WHERE RAND() > 10/90
```

**But this yields an inconsistent split. Is there a way to achieve this properly?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use a **hashing function on one column that discriminates uniquely** each line of your source table (for instance here `orderId`).

BigQuery has a hashing function which target type is a signed `INT64` (and source `STRING` or `BYTES`): `FARM_FINGERPRINT` (from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#farm_fingerprint)).

A solution is to encode each line according to its `FARM_FINGERPRINT(orderId)` which is a sample from a uniform distribution of all `INT64` numbers.

For a given `k`, `MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(orderId)),k)` constitutes a uniform distribution of integers in `[0,k-1]` (Be wary that `MOD(a,b)` with `a` negative and `b` positive may return a negative number).

*Thus, assume you want a 10%/90% split.*

*The queries for each of the splits would look like:*

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   `mytable`
WHERE MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(orderId)),10) = 0
```

and

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   `mytable`
WHERE MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(orderId)),10) != 0
```

**It can be generalised to any 1/k split:**

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   `mytable`
WHERE MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(orderId)),@k) = 0
```

and

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM
   `mytable`
WHERE MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(orderId)),@k) != 0
```

Changing the value of the discriminative mod integer (`0` in the above) allows to have up to `k` different splits (which can be very useful if you are doing multiple-fold cross validation in ML for instance).

Last but not least:

- the folds are robust to data addition in the table
- the folds remain unchanged, whenever the queries are ran